# Class and Module with the same name - how to choose one or another?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, module

I have encountered following situation:

There is

```
ModuleA::ModuleB::ClassC.do_something
```

in the definition of do_something I need to use model from the application

```
def do_something
...
    data = Order.all
...
end
```

But there also exists a module

```
ModuleA::Order
```

So I get an error

```
undefined method `all' for ModuleA::Order:Module
```

I found a solution by doing

```
def do_something
...
    data = Kernel.const_get('Order').all
...
end
```

That returns the model. My question is:
what's the best way to do it? is there a cleaner solution?
(despite the fact, that having the same name for Class and Module it's not the greatest idea, but it cannot be changed here...)

Comment: Having the same name for class and a module is not so bad idea. You just have to be careful with scopes.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Prefix the class name with `::` in the `do_something` method...

```
def do_something
...
    data = ::Order.all
...
end
```